# Bad Request using python_HTTP:400

Tags: python-3.x, http, web-scraping, urllib2

Im using python 3 to scrape facebook page of "nytimes".
I tried to create my own Api first so i can get my app_id && app_secret.
when i tried to ping NYT's Facebook page to verify that the access_token works and the page_id is valid i got this ERROR.

**HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request**

My code is Below

First connect to my API via id and secret code.

```
`   
import urllib
import datetime
import json
import time
import urllib.request
id = "111111111111"
secret ="123123123123123113"
token = id +"|"+ secret`
```

Second To ping the page i did:
`page_id = 'nytimes'`
Then

`def testFacebookPageData(page_id, token):`

```
# construct the URL string
base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
node = "/" + page_id
parameters = "/?token=%s" % token
url = base + node + parameters

# retrieve data
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = json.loads(response.read())

print (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

`testFacebookPageData(page_id, token)`
Hope that im clear..
I need your help
thank You

Answer (score 0):

According to [Facebooks docs for Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens), the parameter should be named `access_token`, and not `token`.

```
parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % token
```

Comment: Thank you! but i did this but i have still the same problem.